# How do I format the data from a randomly pulled dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a game that functions similar to HigherLower, where the user is asked to guess which of the two random people has more followers.

In it, I have a list called data that contains many dictionaries in it. Each dictionary contains a person's info displayed as such:

```
{
    'name': 'John',
    'follower_count': 250,
    'description': 'Musician',
    'country': 'United States'
},
```

To pull a random dictionary from the list, I am using the following function:

```
def get_random_account():
  return random.choice(data)
```

So my question is: How do I call or reference the data in this randomly pulled dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Call your function and assign its result to a variable:

```
user_1 = get_random_account()
user_2 = get_random_account()
guess = input(f"Guess which of {user_1['name']} or {user_2['name']} has more followers: ")
# etc
```